# Set the particular row and column zeros except the diagonal elements in matlab

Tags: matlab

Lets say I am given some indices like `B = [10 23 32....];`

Now lets say I have a matrix A. What I want to do is for each index from B lets say i, I want to set the ith row and ith column of A to 0 except the diagonal element A(i,i)(it remains untouched).

I can do this by looping. But I want some that is based upon some matrix multiplication which is quicker than just looping.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Did any of the solutions provided here work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the diagonal elements temporarily somewhere else, index into A with B to set the corresponding rows and columns to zeros and finally plug back in the diagonal elements -

```
%// rows in A
rows = size(A,1);

%// Store the diagonal elements temporarily somewhere else
tmp_diagA = A(1:rows+1:end);

%// Set the ith rows and cols (obtained from B) to zero
A(B,:)=0;
A(:,B)=0;

%// Plug back in the diagonal elements in place
A(1:rows+1:end) = tmp_diagA;
```

Function calls are supposed to be expensive in MATLAB and we have almost have no function calls in this code, so I am hoping it to be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is:

create the linear indexes of the diagonal elements:

```
[I, J]=size(A);
idx=sub2ind([I,J], B, B);
```

Set the horizontals and verticals to 0 and replace the diagonal elements:

```
NewA=A;
NewA(B, :)=zeros(numel(B),J);
NewA(:, B)=zeros(I,numel(B));
NewA(idx)=A(idx);
```

Comment: Think it should be `A(idx)` at the end.

Comment: This should be pretty fast too.

Answer (score 1):

For square `A`:

```
b = zeros(size(A,1),1);
b(B) = B;
A = A.*bsxfun(@eq, b, b.')
```

For general `A`:

```
b1 = zeros(size(A,1),1);
b1(B) = B;
b2 = zeros(1,size(A,2));
b2(B) = B;
A = A.*bsxfun(@eq, b1, b2);
```

Comment: I don't think entire i-th rows and cols are set to zero with `bsxfun`.

Comment: @Divakar Corrected. Thanks! Very helpful as usual

Comment: Works now! Good use of mask. +1

Answer (score 0):

Suppose,

```
B=[10 23 32 12 15 18 20]
M=true(6)
M(B)=false  %making the indexed elements false
M=or(M,diag(true(size(M,1),1)))  %keep the diagonal elements one

% creating a matrix which has zero in ith row and ith column and diagonal has ones
M1=and(bsxfun(@or,bsxfun(@and,repmat(min(M,[],2),1,size(M,2)),min(M,[],1)),diag(true(size(M,1),1))),M)  

%Now just multiply M1 with your matrix A, and you are done.
newA=A.*M1
```

You can combine above two lines in one, but I prefer them disjoint for readability purposes.